# jquery ui accordion expanding in one click but not collapsing in second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

i have accordion while clicking once its expanding (opening) but while i clicking again on that its not closing the accordion. how to change the function so that i can close the accordion when i click second time to the accordion.

```js
$(function() {
  var icons = {
    header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
    activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
  };
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    icons: icons
  });
  $("#toggle").button().on("click", function() {
    if ($("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons")) {
      $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", null);
    } else {
      $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", icons);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<section class="content">
  <h1 style="color:#B94A7E"> header 1</h1>
  <div id="accordion">
    <h3 style="font-size:16px">header 3</h3>
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <font color="#5a5453">
                                  4. The actual IoT platform that builds, connects and manages includes all APIs, Web services, application
                                  services, agents, connectivity etc
                              </font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick fix, set `collapsible:true` in your accordion option. For e.g.

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
   collapsible: true
});
```

See the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JimUBC/d6mSA/)

Answer (score 0):

An accordion doesnot allow more than one content panel to be open at the same time.Read [JQuery UI documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/) for Accordion.Usually what you want to achieve can be written with few line of jquery code itself as below

```
$('#accordion').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle('slow');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yqTkN/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/g8yoqmsL pasted your code and fixed in fiddle.

```
 $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
   collapsible: true
 });
```

Docs here http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible